# How can I restore windows font to factory?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, fonts

I installed a bunch of fonts on my windows 10 PC, a font hijacked my default windows font and make things difficult to see. I have tried changing the font-substitute using reg edit. Nothing seem to be working. Any help please. I can't afford to reset my PC. An this is affecting my eyes.

Comment: Have you tried to simply remove the Fonts you added?

Comment: Under: 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts', do you still have the 'Segoe UI' entries? "Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf" etc.?

Comment: It is denying me access to delete some fonts. "Segoe (TrueType)"="Segoeui.ttf". After running a registry script I got Online, desktop icons show regular texts. But my browsers and vscode interface use this font.